# Gradient backround for FAB in Jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to add a Floating Action Button with a gradient background in Jetpack Compose. I have the following snippet to do so:

```
FloatingActionButton(
    onClick = {
        coroutineScope.safeLaunch {
            navController.navigate("AddTodoPage") {
                launchSingleTop = true
            }
        }
    },
    shape = RoundedCornerShape(14.dp),
    backgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
    modifier = Modifier
        .constrainAs(addFab) {
            bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
            end.linkTo(parent.end)
        }
        .offset(x = (-16).dp, y = (-24).dp)
        .background(
            brush = Brush.verticalGradient(
                colors = BluePinkGradient()
            ),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(14.dp)
        )

) {
    Icon(
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_add),
        contentDescription = "Add icon",
        tint = Color.White
    )
}

fun BluePinkGradient(inverse: Boolean = false) = when (inverse) {
    true -> listOf(
        MutedBlue,
        MutedPink
    )
    false -> listOf(
        MutedPink,
        MutedBlue
    )
}
val MutedBlue = Color(0xFF26A69A)
val MutedPink = Color(0xFFEC407A)
```

But from the image below, the button has a "Whitish" shade on the plus icon. How can I remove that shade or a better way to set the FAB background to a gradient?
[Fab Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Slv38.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'"Whitish" shade on the plus icon' is the result of `elevation` parameter. You can zero it, but it doesn't looks like you need FAB in the first place.

As you need to custom the button that much, you can use [`IconButton`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary?IconButton(kotlin.Function0%2Candroidx.compose.ui.Modifier%2Ckotlin.Boolean%2Candroidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource%2Ckotlin.Function0)#IconButton(kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource,kotlin.Function0)) instead:

```
IconButton(
    onClick = {
    },
    modifier = Modifier
        .background(
            brush = Brush.verticalGradient(
                colors = BluePinkGradient()
            ),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(14.dp)
        )

) {
    Icon(
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_undo),
        contentDescription = "Add icon",
        tint = Color.White
    )
}
```

[`FloatingActionButton`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#FloatingActionButton(kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.material.FloatingActionButtonElevation,kotlin.Function0)) is only applying some Material defaults to the content, it doesn't make it really floating, it has to be done with the container.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me but I had to modify and  add a `Card` composable container for `.offset(x = (-16).dp, y = (-24).dp),` and `elevation`. The offset behaved weirdly when set on the `IconButton`.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is the best solution.

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.CircleShape
import androidx.compose.material.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.clip
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Brush
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun GradientFloatingActionButton(
    size: Dp = 56.dp,
    gradientColors: List<Color>,
    elevation: Dp = 0.dp,
    onClick: () -> Unit,
    content: @Composable() (BoxScope.() -> Unit)
) {
    val shape = CircleShape
    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(size)
            .clip(shape)
            .background(Brush.linearGradient(gradientColors)),
        color = Color.Transparent,
        onClick = onClick,
        shape = shape,
        elevation = elevation,
        content = {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(6.dp),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
                content = content
            )

        }
    )
}
```

Preview exemple:

```kotlin
@Preview
@Composable
fun GradientFloatingActionButtonPreview() {
    val gradientColors = listOf(Color(0xFF7DFF6C), Color(0xFF008B80))
    GradientFloatingActionButton(
        gradientColors = gradientColors,
        onClick = {}
    ) {
        Icon(
            imageVector = Icons.Filled.CameraAlt,
            contentDescription = "Add icon",
            tint = Color.White
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have developed the following solution, which I have confirmed as working:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun CrazyFloatingActionButton(
    onClick: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    interactionSource: MutableInteractionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
    shape: Shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.small.copy(CornerSize(percent = 50)),
    gradient: List<Color>,
    contentColor: Color = contentColorFor(gradient[0]),
    elevation: FloatingActionButtonElevation = FloatingActionButtonDefaults.elevation(),
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    Surface(
        modifier = modifier,
        shape = shape,
        contentColor = contentColor,
        elevation = elevation.elevation(interactionSource).value,
        onClick = onClick,
        role = Role.Button,
        interactionSource = interactionSource,
        indication = rememberRipple()
    ) {
        CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentAlpha provides contentColor.alpha) {
            ProvideTextStyle(MaterialTheme.typography.button) {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .defaultMinSize(minWidth = 56.dp, minHeight = 56.dp)
                        .background(brush = Brush.verticalGradient(gradient)),
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                ) { content() }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just prepend `Crazy` to your Composable and you should be good to go.